# Errors in BUGS model

Tags: bayesian, mcmc

I'm attempting to run this BUGS model, but am running into some errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
model {
  for (i in 1:n){
    y[i] ~ dnorm (a[state[i]] + theta*treat[i] + b*hispanic, tau.y)
  }
    theta ~ dnorm (0, .0001)
    b ~ dnorm (0, 1000)
  for (j in 1:J){
    a[j] ~ rnorm (mu.a, tau.a^2)
  }
  mu.a ~ dnorm (0, .0001)
  tau.a <- pow (sigma.a, -2)
  sigma.a ~ dunif (0, 100)
  tau.y <- pow (sigma.y, -2)
  sigma.y <- dunif (0, 100)
}
```

Comment: More detail is useful. What errors? Which BUGS software? Run from terminal? Through R?

Comment: Why is tau.a squared, when it is already converted to precision?

Comment: If openBUGS or WinBUGS you can't put calculations into dnorm in line 3, these need to be done separately then passed, though this should be ok in JAGS.